# Interchaning limits of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Fix $0<a<b$. How would you change the limits of integrations $\int_a^b\int_0^ydxdy$ to something so you were integrating with respect to $y$ first? $\int_0^a\int_x^bdydx$ isn't right. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why would you need to do that when you can simply do: $$\int_a^b\int_0^y\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=\int_a^b y\,\mathrm dy=\frac 12(b^2-a^2)$$

Comment: I omitted the integrand from the problem. It's $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. Then the issue is integrating arcsin for the second integral (you can use integration by parts, but I'd like to see this method)

Comment: Note that the integrand is $f(x)g(y)$ where $f(x):=\dfrac 1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and $g(y)=1$, so can you split it into product of two integrals?

Comment: To understand the problem, forget the particular integrand and replace it with $f(x,y)$, then use the indicator function $\int_{\Bbb{R}^2} 1_{\text{domain of integration}}$.

Comment: Yes, I originally left the integrand out. I'm just not seeing how to rewrite this region with $g(x)\leq y\leq h(x)$ first.

Comment: [Fubini Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing the integration region helps. $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$
$$\int_a^b \int_0^y f(x) \,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy =
\int_0^a \int_a^b f(x) \,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx +\int_a^b \int_x^b f(x) \,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: yes, I initially thought to break it up like that too, but then you still have a problem integrating the first integral on the right because the limits of integration don't contain an $x$.

Comment: Ah wait, never mind. I think I see now. Thank you